# How can I upgrade Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, upgrade

What's the best way to upgrade Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu?

For the time being, I was periodically getting the newest version (.deb) from their [official site](https://code.visualstudio.com/):

```
sudo dpkg -i code_*.deb
```

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Visual Studio Code enabled official Linux repositories on [February 2017 (v1.10)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10)

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main "
sudo apt update
sudo apt -y install code
```

You can upgrade / dist-upgrade as usual

```
sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt -y dist-upgrade
```

Comment: In Debian 9.3.0 clean LDXE, the procedure above worked after I `sudo apt-get install` the following additional packages: `software-properties-common apt-transport-https`

Comment: I used `sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main "` to avoid getting a unsupported architecture message.

Answer (score 22):

1. download the latest Visual Studio Code (*.deb*) package to your computer on this link:

   https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868

   , or this there: *[Getting Started](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/)*
2. then open a terminal in the folder where you downloaded the *.deb* file and write:

   ```
    sudo dpkg -i <the downloaded file>.deb
   ```
3. finally, if you have [apt-get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)), do (if not, install *apt-get* first):

   ```
    sudo apt-get install -f
   ```

Answer (score 21):

If you have installed it via [the repository](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux), exit Visual Studio Code, and then just do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install code
```

This is the same command to install or upgrade to the latest version. You can see the version with:

```
code --version
```

[Now](https://snapcraft.io/blog/visual-studio-code-launches-as-a-snap) the easiest and recommended way is to use [snap](https://snapcraft.io/code):

```
sudo snap install --classic code
```

And updates are supposed to be automatic.

Answer (score 9):

This works fine in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install code
```

Answer (score 6):

1. When you install Visual Studio Code with the file .deb on Ubuntu 20.08, first, remove it:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove code
   ```
2. Add the repository in this link https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

   ```
    wget -qO- https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > packages.microsoft.gpg
    sudo install -o root -g root -m 644 packages.microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/
    sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/packages.microsoft.gpg] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list'
   ```
3. Udate the package cache and reinstall

   ```
    sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install code
   ```
4. In the next time when you want to upgrade, just do:

   ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade code
   ```

Because your repository is missing information to upgrade Visual Studio Code, the above solution will fix it.

Comment: There isn't any Ubuntu 20.08. Do you mean [Ubuntu 20.04.8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa)?

Comment: Though the last one in 20.04 appears [to be 20.04.6](https://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/)(?). Is there a Ubuntu 20.04.8?

Comment: We are probably in a [DenverCoder9](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients) situation: *"[Last seen more than 1 year ago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7738910/l%c3%aa-v%c5%a9-l%c3%a2m)"*. Can somebody else chime in?

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did to avoid the annoying message:

1. Remove Visual Studio Code, if you already installed it.

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove code
   ```
2. Add repositories, update and install:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main "
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt -y install code
   ```

Answer (score 2):

The following commands work for me (for Linux):

```
wget 'https://code.visualstudio.com/sha/download?build=stable&os=linux-deb-x64' -O /tmp/code_latest_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/code_latest_amd64.deb
```

Place those two commands into an executable Bash script called *auto-update-VSCode*, and you can simply run that from your shell any time Visual Studio Code says it's out of date.

Comment: What Linux? Ubuntu? What version of Ubuntu was it tested on?

Comment: What are other valid parameters than `build=stable`? Would it also work for those?

Comment: What are other valid parameters than `build=stable`? `insider`? `monthly`? `weekly`? Would it also work for those? Where is the documentation for those parameters? The answer could be extended with some of this information. *[Download Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)*. *[What are the differences between Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio Code Insider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53944549/)*

Answer (score 1):

I'm running [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa), and this worked perfectly for me:

```
wget https://vscode-update.azurewebsites.net/latest/linux-deb-x64/stable -O /tmp/code_latest_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i /tmp/code_latest_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I get 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed Visual Studio Code, go to the terminal and type two different commands:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade code`

Comment: duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/77376211/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to update Visual Studio Code in Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install code
```

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/77376211/

Answer (score -1):

I'm using [Kali Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Linux) and this option worked for me:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade code`

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/a/77376211/

Answer (score -3):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install code
```

Comment: Duplicates existing answer(s) without adding additional information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77376211/