# What are the differences between Visual Studio Code and Visual Studio Code Insider?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) vs.
[Visual Studio Code Insider](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)

I still do not understand what the difference is between the two. Could it be that one of them is a trial version for its new functionalities?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Visual Studio Code Insiders is just a beta version. It includes the latest features and bug fixes, but new features may or may not be stable.

You can have both versions of the program installed, and you can open them simultaneously. You can also keep settings easily synced between the two with the [Settings Sync extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync).

Comment: I've removed the self-promotional link, since it doesn't improve the answer in any way. I don't think SO is a good place to promote your course. (Linking, let's say, to an article of yours on the topic of the question would be ok. But promoting a course that hasn't even been released yet is too much, IMO.)

Comment: Proof that "clever" naming often backfires: the fact that we have to look up a "new app" simply because the app authors did not want to call it "Visual Studio Code Beta Version" or something else that would be totally obvious and self-explanatory.

Comment: In Ubuntu Snap, I can install `code`, `vscode` and `code-insiders`. The last one I know, `vscode` seems like a community version from snapcrafters without updates and code is the official MS one.

Answer (score 10):

[Insiders Build](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/) is a pre-release version of the Visual Studio Code where you can try the new features. It is updated daily with the latest bugfixes and feature updates from the day before. You can have a look here for a more clear definition of Visual Studio Code Insiders build: *[Visual Studio Code FAQ, *Prerelease versions*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_prerelease-versions)*